# Leaflet Map Attribution Data

Tags: leaflet, dataset, gis, attribution

I'd like a dataset (json probably) having common GIS attributions to show on a map. I believe I once saw a fairly large one, maybe a leaflet gist or data file?

Does anyone know where such a dataset might be?